# The self keyword in the context of rails associations

Tags: ruby

I'm working through the rails tutorial and have come across this code. I'm having trouble understanding what the self keyword in this context could be doing. From what I understand the self keyword is a way to create class functions that belong to their creating object but I really don't understand what this means.

The code is below:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

 def feed

 end

 def following?(other_user)
  self.relationships.find_by(followed_id: other_user.id)
 end

 def follow!(other_user)
  self.relationships.create!(followed_id: other_user.id)
 end

end
```

Can anyone give a fairly intuitive explanation of this? I'm familiar with the 'this' keyword from other languages but this seems like rails magic. Thank you!

Comment: This is a Ruby thing, not Rails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're familiar with the 'this' keyword, well, 'self' is almost exactly the same, meaning, 'the object currently at hand'. In 'normal' methods, as you show in your example, this means 'the instantiation of your class', in class methods, this means 'the class object itself'. You could also read it as 'my', followed by 'relationships', so 'find in my relationships...'

Comment: So in this case relationships isn't a class method, it is a normal method. Then if this is the case, can you apply self to any method and relate it to the class at hand? I suppose this has to do with message passing - a concept I'm still not completely comfortable with.

Comment: This is indeed a "normal" method. So you're indeed passing the message "relationships" to "self", being the object itself, not its class.

Comment: If you want some additional reading on "self", I would recommend the following article: http://www.jimmycuadra.com/posts/self-in-ruby